# Unable to connect to DynamoDB running locally on Docker

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb

I am running DynamoDB locally on the laptop via docker.

Tried to list tables via: `aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000`

Got the below response:

> You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by running "aws configure".

Ran: aws configure

```
aws configure
AWS Access Key ID []: 
AWS Secret Access Key []: 
Default region name [Asia Pacific (Melbourne)]: 
Default output format [None]: json
```

Now I am getting a new error:

```
aws dynamodb list-tables --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

> Provided region_name 'Asia Pacific (Melbourne)' doesn't match a supported format.

Anyone know how to fix this?. I cannot find this "Output_format" parameter in AWS console settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your `aws configure` didn't work correctly but the region name for the Melbourne AZ is `ap-southeast-4`.

Use this value when configuring via `aws configure`. This should update your `~/.aws/config` file to something like

```properties
[default]
region = ap-southeast-4
output = json
```

Optionally, specify an environment variable

```sh
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=ap-southeast-4
```

or simply append the `region` option to your CLI command

```sh
aws dynamodb list-tables \
  --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000 \
  --region ap-southeast-4
```

See [Configuring the AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Phil, changing the region to ap-southeast-4 worked